# What kind of WiFi Antenna is that Iphone uses?

Tags: antenna

[image]

I dig up on WiFi antennas. What researchers design on their articles looks complex PIFAs, however, this's from Iphone 6. It just looks a rectangular patch to me. I m not sure, what kind of antenna is that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That doesn't even look like an antenna, maybe the black hides something significantly more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this actually is just an antenna, looks more like a composite device made of multiple things.

Anyway,

As explained in my last answer, antennas in phones are the results of long optimization, simulation, optimization, new constraints, … cycles. You won't see a "pure-bred" PIFA, dipole, … in the wild; these antennas are typically a mix of a lot of things, due to the trade-offs they make.

Comment: Thank you again, you're the only one I get answers from. I also thought the black would hide. It's said that its thickness is 1 mm. If we assume the whole antenna under the black, would it mean substrate/s + ground+patch so that the all in one and total thickness is 1 mm?